# Expose Neo4j cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: neo4j, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to deploy a Neo4j [causal cluster](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/clustering/causal-clustering/) in Kubernetes. I've followed [this guide](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/kubernetes-neo4j) on Github, and deployed the cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine and it works as expected, i.e., the cluster replicates writes in the followers, and catch up in case of failure (deleting pods).

What I want to do next  is to expose this cluster to accessed from outside of it.

The challenge I'm facing is that, in order to connect to a remote causal cluster, I need to have a static name/IP address of any of the `CORE` servers, using the `bolt+routing` URI, so that the driver can route the requests accordingly (read, write, etc.).

As it's shown here, the [service](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/kubernetes-neo4j/blob/master/cores/dns.yaml) is exposed as `ClusterIP` mode, so it's only accessible from within the cluster. I have attempted to change it to `NodePort` and `LoadBalancer` modes, and in those cases, the `CORE` Neo4j cluster members cannot find each other.

How can I keep the internal communication of the required ports (Raft, Transactions, etc.) and expose the `7687` (and possibly `7474` for browser) for external communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple `Service`s for the same deployment in Kubernetes.

- have a `ClusterIP` Service, so nodes can continue to communicate with each oter.
- have a `LoadBalancer` Service, so you can expose the public port to the Internet.

If you’re looking to restrict internal communication *further*, you should look at Kubernetes Network Policies (but I doubt that's what you need). Some resources on this:

- https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-networkpolicy-tutorial
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy